# Solution of equation Ax = 0 for singual matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I prove that if $detA = 0$, then there is a not-trivial solution of $$Ax = 0$$ (where $x$ is a vector)? I couldn't think of any proof without using linear operators

Comment: What's wrong with using linear operators? If matrix has $\det A=0$ then this means that the corresponding linear operator $k^n\to k^n$ is not invertible. And for finite dimensional case this means it has nontrivial kernel.

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InvertibleMatrixTheorem.html

Comment: @freakish We haven't learned linear operators yet ...

Comment: What definition or characterization of the determinant do you know? An answer would depend on that.

Comment: It's skew-symmetric multilinear form of matrix rows and columns

Comment: To be honest, that's what I'm trying to prove - if $detA = 0$, then columns of matrix are linearly dependent...